# dropbox api video share_url authorization error

Tags: authorization, dropbox, dropbox-api

when using the api : https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings

like this

```
const getRequest = await axios.post(
                "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings",
                {
                    path: `/${ fileName }`,
                                        settings: {
                        "requested_visibility": "public",
                        "allow_download": "false",
                        "audience": "public",
                        "access": "viewer"
                    }

                                        

                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${ dbxAccessToken }`,
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                },
            );
```

an authorization error occured .

when i modify the sharing.write and generate a refresh token with these scopes nothing changes still the same error ?

is this error because im not using the professional plan or no ?

Comment: What's the error exactly? Print out the full response body to see the error.